# Retornar apenas o primeiro dado de um array em JSON e JAVA

Tags: java, json

Tenho um projeto onde busco no banco de dados via JSON, para exportar esses dados em formato Excel. Estou adicionando uma nova busca, porem tenho um array de string, mas não consigo trazer os dados do banco de forma que me retornasse apenas o primeiro dado desse array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject js2 = js.getJSONObject("cliente").optJSONObject("enderecoList").getJSONObject("municipio");
    JSONObject jsUnidade = js.getJSONObject("unidade");
    JSONObject jsUnidadePai = jsUnidade.getJSONObject("unidadePai");
    JSONObject jsCliente = js.getJSONObject("cliente");
    JSONObject jsApl = js.getJSONObject("apl");
    JSONObject jsSetor = js.getJSONObject("setor");
```

Eu gostaria que ele me retornasse apenas o primeiro dado que encontrasse no array `getJSONObject("municipio")`

Não está escrito `getJSONArray("municipio")`, pois não consigo dar um getString para mostrar o valor retornado.

Sou iniciante em java e JSON.

Comment: mas se você quer que ele te retorne apenas o primeiro dado encontrado no array não da pra fazer algo tipo `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` assim só faz o loop uma vez e te retorna só o primeiro?

Comment: Mas eu preciso do for para me retornar os outros dados.

Comment: Poderia mostrar a estrutura deste JSON? Mas se quer apenas o primeiro item da lista tente assim: **JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);**

Comment: Mas no for você esta determinando que o Objeto **js** recebe **jasonArray.getJSONObject(i)** então se no seu for o i for apenas **for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)** o valor de **I** será apenas **0** assim pegando o primeiro registro encontrado

Comment: Fiz isso, porem ele exporta o arquivo Excel sem nem um dado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa fazer é alterar o código para obter o municipio como um JSONArray, e se for sua necessidade pegar apenas o primeiro elemento, usar o método getJSONObject, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
JSONObject js2 = js.getJSONObject("cliente").optJSONObject("enderecoList")
           .getJSONArray("municipio").getJSONObject(0);
```

Mas ainda seria melhor trazer cada elemento por vez. Algo assim:

```
JSONObject endList = js.getJSONObject("cliente").optJSONObject("enderecoList");
if(js != null) {
    JSONArray jsMunicipios = endList.getJSONArray("municipio");
    if(jsMunicipios.length() > 0) {
        JSONObject primeiroMunicipio = jsMunicipios.getJSONObject(0);
        // Imprime ou usa o primeiro Municipio aqui
    }
}
```

Pois desta forma você tem mais controle sobre o código e depuração de possíveis erros que podem acontecer ao ler o JSON.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou!